# DIV height takes the height of img inside and not the height set using CSS

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, height

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(e){  
       var dheight=$(document).innerHeight();  
       $(".background").css({  
          "height": dheight,  
          "overflow":"hidden"  
       });  
    });  
</script>

<section id="box">
    <section class="heading">
        <div class="head">SiteName</div>
    </section>
    <!--heading-->
    <div class="background">
        <img src="images/hdimage.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <!--background-->
</section>
<!--box-->
```

The problem is in the Internet Explorer (even IE 10) `<div class="background">` takes the aspect height of the image, even I set `height`, `max-height` with `overflow: hidden`.

In Google Chrome, Firefox there is no problem. On inspecting in IE I find IE adds inline style with height of the image to the `<div>`. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: your image tag is missing its closing slash. <img src="xxx" />

Comment: it's better to use http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Is the `img` height greater than the one of the `div`?

Comment: The height of the image should not matter since the div is `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @BaraMara Yes. I want the <div> height to be equal to the screen innerHeight. But the image height exceeds.

Comment: @SuryaS as ra_htial suggested, put your code online. its much easier for people to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your trying to achieve full screen backgrounds, if you are your code is quite far from being complete and working in all instances and browsers.

I think your code may not be working due to the missing closing tag on your img `/>`

Id suggest you take a look at the following code found on [this article](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

```
.background{

         background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
          -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion thеse lines are unpredictable

```
$(document).ready(function(e){  
       var dheight=$(document).innerHeight();
```

When you deal with images since their height is yet unavailable you should wait
for them to load.

```
$(window).on('load',fumction(){
   var dheight=$(document).innerHeight();
   ...
})
```

Is the better option